# JavaScript - Click all buttons with Class Name after 5 seconds (Twitter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter, click

I've been trying to get my script to work for ages now, and it just won't have it! I'm trying to click all the 'unfollow button's on my Twitter/Following page after 5 seconds. Here's my code without the setInterval function:

```
var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('w-button-common w-button-unfollow'); for(var a=0;a<buttonArray.length;a++){ buttonArray[0].click(); }
```

Here's Twitters HTML DOM code for the unfollow buttons:

```
    <span class="w-button-common w-button-unfollow"><input alt="Follow" src="https://ma.twimg.com/twitter-mobile/97bb0ca1daa74ae65fd470b1961897275eb91579/images/sprites/followchecked.gif" type="image"></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="scribe_item" value="description=list&amp;id=1875185790&amp;item_type=3">
</form>
</td>
```

I'd be so appreciated if someone could amend my code! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `buttonArray[0].click()` to `buttonArray[a].click()`.

Comment: I managed to get the function to click all the 'unfollow buttons' by using this: $('.user-actions-follow-button.js-follow-btn.follow-button.btn.small.small-follo‌​w-btn').click(); - I just can't get the setInterval function to programmatically click them every 2 seconds:(

Answer (score 5):

Using jquery you can use like this...

```
$('.w-button-common.w-button-unfollow').click()
```

both of the class is on same element. So, it should not be any spaces in between the class

Comment: I managed to get the function to click all the 'unfollow buttons' by using this: $('.user-actions-follow-button.js-follow-btn.follow-button.btn.small.small-follow-btn').click(); - I just can't get the setInterval function to programmatically click them every 2 seconds:(

Answer (score 0):

The loop index is incorrect

`buttonArray[0].click();` <<< mistake in the for loop

`buttonArray[a].click();` will do the trick.